# how to figure out whats the SEL name used

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, cocoa

I am just curious if there is a way to extract the SEL name dynamically?

Not sure how to extract SEL since its a typedef struct.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please elaborate. However, I believe you are trying to convert a `SEL` to `NSString`. If that is the case, then what you are looking for is:

```
NSString *selectorName = NSStringFromSelector(selector);
```